# Why are sockets used by "wuproxy in C" different from other programming language in the guide?

Tags: zeromq

Why are sockets used by "wuproxy in C" different from other programming language in the guide?
C uses ZMQ_XPUB and ZMQ_XSUB, while C++ uses ZMQ_PUB and ZMQ_SUB.

Answer (score 0):

In the C++ example, the proxy subscribes to everything (`frontend.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);`). The end-client subscribers will therefore get everything sent from the proxy's `PUB`.

In the C example, the use of `ZMQ_XPUB and ZMQ_XSUB` will allow the end-client subscriber to control what they receive, making the proxy more 'transparent'.

For more detail see http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:0mq-3-0-pubsub